# Map stream elements to LocalDate without collecting to list

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors, localdate

Suppose I have a stream of Integers representing daily data:

```
Stream.of(12,19,7,13,42,69);
```

where each number belongs to one date starting from 22.01.2020 and I want to get a map `Map<LocalDate,Integer>`.

So basicaly I need smth like:

```
22.01.2020  = 12
23.01.2020  = 19
24.01.2020  = 7
25.01.2020  = 13
26.01.2020  = 42
27.01.2020  = 69
```

How do I increment the key (LocalDate) starting at a given date(ex. 22.01.2020)?

```
Map<LocalDate,Integer> map = Stream.of(12,19,7,13,42,69)
              .collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> **LocalDate.of(2020,1,22)**, x -> x));
```

Comment: So in your example do you want to find the key that equals 22/01/2020 and change it to 23/01/2020?

Comment: @mohammedkhan No. My first key is fixed and is the 22.01.2020. The corresponding value should be the first elemnt from the stream. The second key should be first key plus one day, 23.01.2020 and value next value from stream-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A cleaner solution could be to use `IntStream` such as:

```
LocalDate firstDay = LocalDate.of(2020, Month.JANUARY, 22);
List<Integer> data = List.of(12, 19, 7, 13, 42, 69);
Map<LocalDate, Integer> finalMap = IntStream.range(0, data.size())
        .mapToObj(day -> Map.entry(firstDay.plusDays(day), data.get(day)))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Or if you were stuck with `Stream<Integer>` as data input using `AtomicInteger` wouldn't be a bad idea either with a restriction to perform sequential execution:

```
LocalDate firstDay = LocalDate.of(2020, Month.JANUARY, 22);
AtomicInteger dayCount = new AtomicInteger();
Map<LocalDate, Integer> finalMap = Stream.of(12, 19, 7, 13, 42, 69)
        .map(data -> Map.entry(firstDay.plusDays(dayCount.getAndIncrement()), data))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
System.out.println(finalMap);
```

Comment: Your second approach was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's slightly difficult to achieve this, mainly because you're working with both a `Stream<LocalDate>` and a `Stream<Integer>`. One **hack** is to store the starting date in a single-element array and modify it inside the `Collector`:

```
LocalDate[] startDate = { LocalDate.of(2020, Month.JANUARY, 21) };

Map<LocalDate, Integer> map = Stream.of(12, 19, 7, 13, 42, 69)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> {
        startDate[0] = startDate[0].plusDays(1L);
        return startDate[0];
    }, Function.identity()));

System.out.println(map);
```

The output of this is:

```
{2020-01-27=69, 2020-01-26=42, 2020-01-25=13, 2020-01-24=7, 2020-01-23=19, 2020-01-22=12}
```

A cleaner solution would be to create a custom `Collector` so you could support collecting a parallel `Stream`.

Comment: Will try to understand what is going on here and give feedback soon.

Comment: I am a noob to create a a custom Collector ;-) Your solution works for me. If i get it right you are overriding the startdate over and over. Aren't you? After this code startdate[0] will be 27.01.2020, is that right?

Comment: You're correct. We wrap the `LocalDate` in an array, as all variables used inside a lambda (that are declared outside of it) must be effectively final. Then, we simply increment the value by 1 day for each element in your `Stream<Integer>`.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: What if you execute this in parallel?

Comment: @RavindraRanwala Then you're SOL :), which is why creating a custom collector would be a better solution.